# iOS - How to set a string to the title of a button

Tags: ios, variables

I am making an app in Xcode and I want the variable "selectedAnswer" to be set to the title/text of my button answer1. answer1 is a IBOutlet and an IBAction.

Comment: Did you even check the Apple docs or SO for other posts ?

Comment: No, where will i locate them?

Comment: So before starting developing you should start learning how to use Google. Just type `UIButton` on the google and the first page there will be `https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html` which is the apple docs for the UIButton class ;). Then in that page do a search for `setTitle` this will give you the method used in the answers below

Answer (score 1):

```
[answer1 setTitle:selectedAnswer forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Miss understanding, selectedAnswer is the variable

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
  NSString *selectedAnswer = @"Title";
  [answer1 setTitle: selectedAnswer forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this code:

```
 [answer1 setTitle:selectedAnswer forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```